# Oracle apex (19.1) - hide interactive report panel when table is empty

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I got an interactive report with a "collapsible" template.

When the table is empty there is an empty panel that takes up a lot of space. In Classic report this space does not exist when the table is empty.
I can't find a way that interactive report will behave the same way (we don't want to use Classic report).
I need a simple generic solution since we have a lot of tables.

The interactive report looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like this (as Classic report):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply an after-refresh dynamic action that checks for the existence of the nodatafound area, and hide/treat the region in some way:

```
$(this.triggeringElement).find('.nodatafound').length == 1
```

Or you could apply a different amount of padding to the .a-IRR-noDataMsg class

```
.a-IRR-noDataMsg {padding: 5px;}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I'm still looking to find global solution without adding dynamic action to each table. Currently I found solution in the app Javacript page similar to yours:  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - $('.icon-irr-no-results').closest('.a-IRR-noDataMsg-icon').closest('.a-IRR-noDataMsg').hide()  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
But this solution works only when opening a new page, and not when getting an empty table after deleting existing rows. So maybe I'm looking for more "Apex" solution then dynamic JS

Comment: The CSS option can be applied by default on every page - it would be part of the render.